# How to add alive object to NSMutableArray and remove them when they're released?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablearray

I have class Item and class List (which has an NSMutableArray).

Every time class Item is instantiated (and destroyed) it posts a notification, which is listened-to by class List.  When class List receives the notification is adds the instance of class Item to its list.

I'm trying to have class Item also post a notification that its about to be dealloc'd.  The problem is that class List's NSMutableArray retains the instance of class Item.

What's the most appropriate means of handling this situation?  If I decrement the count when adding it to List's array, then an exception will be thrown when class List attempts to call removeObject (since it'll try to dealloc the object.)

Basically, I want a "monitor" class List that contains a list of all "live" instances of Item.  But, I also need the ability to release/dealloc the instances and have them report they're being dealloc'd so List can remove them from its NSMutableArray.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your application is and if this would apply, but be wary of using dealloc to inform you of things being destroyed as this can be delayed or never happen

Comment: +1 thanks for the interesting question. it caused me to use associated objects in ways that i've never thought of before :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want an array that maintains weak references to its items, as opposed to strong references?

<strike>I don't know of a way to do this with anything "built-in" in Cocoa.  The only way I'd know of to do this is to make the array yourself, and have the storage be `__weak id[]`.  That would automatically zero-out the place in the array when the object deallocates.  If you're under the retain-release model, you could use something like [`MAZeroingWeakRef`](https://github.com/mikeash/MAZeroingWeakRef) to get the same behavior.</strike>

This is definitely an interesting question, and I don't know of an easier answer.  I'd love to be proven wrong!

Ha, I love being wrong!

There's a class called [`NSPointerArray`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPointerArray_Class/Introduction/Introduction.html) that looks like it can do what you're looking for.  However, it's only available on the Mac, and it only auto-zeros when you're using garbage collection.

I'll keep thinking about this.  This is an interesting problem! :)

---

So I kept thinking about this, and came up with a solution.  It uses two unconventional things:

1. A subclass of `NSMutableArray` (egads!)
2. Using an associated object to determine object deallocation

For the first bit, I had to to subclass `NSMutableArray` so that I could inject some custom logic into `addObject:` (and related methods).  I didn't want to do this via swizzling, since `NSArray` and friends are a class cluster, and swizzling into/out of clusters is fraught with peril.  So, a subclass.  This is fine, but we're going to lose some of the awesome features we get from "pure" `NSArray` instances, like [how they do weird things when they get big](http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/archives/2005/12/23/array/).  Oh well, such is life.

As for the second bit, I needed a way for any arbitrary object to notify that it is about to or just finished deallocating.  I thought of dynamically subclassing the object's class, injecting my own `dealloc`/`finalize` method, calling `super`, and then smashing the `isa` of the object, but that just seemed a little too crazy.

So, I decided to take advantage of a fun little thing called associated objects.  These are to ivars what categories are to classes: they allow you to dynamically add and remove pseudo-instance variables at runtime.  They also have the awesome side effect of getting automatically cleaned up with the object deallocates.  So what I did is just created a little throw away object that posts a notification when *it* is deallocated, and then attached it to the regular object.  That way when the regular object is deallocated, the throw away object will be as well, resulting in a notification being posted, which I then listen for in the `NSMutableArray` subclass.  The notification contains a (stale) pointer to the object that is in the process of getting destroyed, but since I only care about the *pointer* and not the *object*, that's OK.

The upshot of all of this is that you can do:

```
DDAutozeroingArray *array = [DDAutozeroingArray array];

NSObject *o = [[NSObject alloc] init];
[array addObject:o];
NSLog(@"%ld", [array count]); //logs "1"
[o release];
NSLog(@"%ld", [array count]); //logs "0"
```

The source is on github, and it should (theoretically) work just as well on iOS as Mac OS X (regardless of GC mode): https://github.com/davedelong/Demos

Cheers!

---

... and I just thought of a way to do this without a custom subclass, but I'm tired and will post the updated answer tomorrow.

---

*the next morning...*

I've just updated the project on Github with an `NSMutableArray` category that allows you to create a true `NSMutableArray` that auto-zeroes its objects as they're deallocated.  The trick was to create a `CFMutableArrayRef` with a custom `retain` callback that sets up the proper observation, and then just cast that `CFMutableArrayRef` to an `NSMutableArray` and use that (ah, the magic of Toll-Free Bridging).

This means you can now do:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray autozeroingArray];
```

I added a `typedef` to define these as `NSAutozeroingMutableArray`, just to make it explicitly clear that while this is an `NSMutableArray`, it doesn't `retain` its objects like a normal `NSMutableArray`.  However, since it's just a `typedef` and not a subclass, you can use them interchangeably.

Comment: Ha, you’ve edited your question whilst I was typing my answer! :-P

Comment: @Bavarious +1 to you for being right the first time; I'm still thinking about ways you could get this to work without GC (and therefore on iOS)

Comment: Wouldn’t `NSValue` objects with pointers work on iOS? It could be an `NSMutableArray` whose elements are `NSValue` instances with pointers to `Item` instances, and use the same notifications. The main ‘issue’ would be the indirection when accessing `Item` objects in the array.

Comment: @Bavarious sure, but they wouldn't be auto-zeroing.  Heck, if you wanted a weak reference array, you could just cast a `CFMutableArrayRef` with custom  value callbacks to an `NSMutableArray` and use that.  It's the auto-zeroing that's interesting.

Comment: True that. Hope you’re able to devise a solution that does auto-zeroing. :)

Comment: @Bavarious thought of a way, though it requires some trickery

Comment: I believe you are adding the array as observer to notifications from observed, but unregistering for notifications from the content object.

Comment: +1 for general awesomeness, and for the ridiculousfish link in particular. Also, you really seem to need the reputation points.

Answer (score 5):

I haven’t tested this, so comments are welcome.

You could use an `NSPointerArray` for the list (in a `retain` property):

```
self.array = [NSPointerArray pointerArrayWithWeakObjects];
```

When an `Item` object is created, it would post a notification that’s listened by your `List` class. Upon receiving the notification, `List` adds the object to the pointer array:

```
[array addPointer:pointerToTheObject];
```

In this setting, the pointer array doesn’t keep a strong reference to its elements — in particular, it doesn’t retain them. This applies to both garbage-collected and non-garbage-collected builds.

In a garbage-collected build, if an element is garbage collected then the garbage collector automatically assigns `NULL` to the position in the array where the object was stored.

In a non-garbage-collected build, you’ll need to manually remove the element or assign `NULL` to the position in the array where it was stored. You can do this by overriding `-[Item dealloc]` and posting a notification that the object is being deallocated. Your `List` class, upon receiving the notification, would act upon it.

Note that, since objects are not owned by the pointer array, you must keep a strong reference to (or retain) them if you want to keep them alive.