# Why is KVO retaining all of NSMutableArray's objects?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, key-value-observing, key-value-coding, retaincount

I'm having a real pain trying to figure out why KVO is retaining all values that are being observed.

Scenario: I have an NSMutableArray with weak references.  (Set up with CFArrayCreateMutable and Callback having NULL for both retain and release).  Meaning any object added is never retained / released.

I have an NSArrayController observing values of the NSMutableArray.

But now, every object of the NSMutableArray is also retained.  Why is this happening and how do I stop this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know that something is retaining these objects? You're not looking at -retainCount, are you? If yes, don't do that.

If you read about [the way KVO works](http://tinyurl.com/3pzgn45), you'll find that there are some objects created behind the scenes when you start observing objects. You really don't need to know or think about those objects in order to use KVO successfully -- indeed, there's not much that you *can* know -- but you also shouldn't worry about who other than yourself might or might not be retaining things.

Comment: @David, right, I remember [your question about automatically adding/removing objects from an array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5972808/643383). You may not be looking at `-retainCount`, but you're still counting on `-dealloc` being called at a particular time, and you're making assumptions about the behavior of other objects. Any time you try to do something like "compensate for KVO," you're wrong and getting more wrong. ;-) Also, note that if an object is in a mutable array, it's `-dealloc` should never be called because the array itself will have retained the object. I'm sure you know that.

Comment: @David, technically, a leak is different: it's a chunk of memory that can never be deallocated because nobody has a reference to it. What you've got is more like a retain cycle, except that it's not really a cycle, just an unanticipated retain that's getting in your way. I think I appreciate the cleverness of what you're trying to do, but at the same time it's the assumption you're making about other objects that's causing the problem. Assuming you're using DDAutozeroingArray, the short answer is probably that it doesn't support KVO.