# How to remove an object from NSMutableArray only when retain count reaches 0?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, shared-memory, retaincount

I know I'm not supposed to check or use retainCount, but I'm trying to wonder if there's a way to have an object be removed from an NSMutableArray only after its retain count is 0.

Basically, I want to add objects to an array, and have those objects be shared among other windows.  When a window uses it, I want the retain count to go up by 1.  When it's no longer used, I want it to go down.  But, if some window is still using it, then I want it to be available to all other windows.  When all windows are no longer using it, then I want it to be removed form the array and released entirely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **automatic removal from array on release** you could use **associated objects**, as Dave DeLong described here:
[How to add alive object to NSMutableArray and remove them when they're released?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972808/how-to-add-alive-object-to-nsmutablearray-and-remove-them-when-theyre-released)

But you'd probably be better off using an [`NSCountedSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html), as **it implements exactly what you're after**. It just **lacks item order**.
To make up with the lack of item order you could use an **additional `NSMutableArray`** to keep order and add/remove items to/from it **in sync with your counted set**.

Comment: Yep.  That was my own question.  It doesn't solve my problem actually. In fact, it presents a whole new KVO problem.  If I monitor the array with KVO then each object in that array is retained, so nothing ever gets released.  No clue why.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6400627/why-is-kvo-retaining-all-of-nsmutablearrays-objects

Comment: @david: If you're not dependent on item order use an NSCountedSet (see updated answer).

Comment: The problem is that NS*Set doesn't support KVO.  So I can't monitor what's in the set.

Comment: While none of both do exacty what you need, combining them can bring you the best of both worlds. Use an NSMutableArray as you used to and add an additional NSCountedSet which you utilize to check for membership counts (update/query on every add/remove from array, which you could observe via KVO).